# Vue3 Creating Component Instances Programmatically on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In vue2 it was be easy:

```
<template>
 <button :class="type"><slot /></button>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   name: 'Button',
   props: [ 'type' ],
 }
</script>
```

```
import Button from 'Button.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Button)
var instance = new ComponentClass()

instance.$mount() // pass nothing
this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

extend + create instance. But in vue3 it's has been deleted. Where are another way?

Comment: Why are you instantiating components this way (via DOM manipulation) instead of standard Vue idioms (i.e., templates or render functions)?

Comment: @tony19 because it's just an example, real production way wait backend answer and render it with backend data

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import {defineComponent,createApp} from 'vue'

buttonView = defineComponent({
    extends: Button, data() {
        return {
            type: "1111"
        }
    }
})

const div = document.createElement('div');
this.$refs.container.appendChild(div);
createApp(buttonView ).mount(div)
```

Comment: how do I `v-bind:` programmatically ? I have `type: var`, but when I change the value of var, it does not update

Comment: Could you explain what is `this` in `this.$refs.container.appendChild(div);`?

Comment: Dependency injection does not work in this case

Comment: @Artemiy How do you listen to events on the "app" created and how do you destroy it when you don't need it anymore? In Vue 2 something like instance.$on('event',  cb) was possible, and to destroy a simple instance.$destroy() was possible. How would you do it now?

Comment: @darkylmnx ask new question please, this is not about above theme

Comment: Make sure you turn on runtime compilation (depending on your bundler).
When using Vue CLI for example you need to have the option `runtimeCompiler: true` (in vue.config.js) Otherwise you'll get a warning saying rendering wont work: `Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using options API, in a method create a component

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";


createComponent() {
var component = {
   data() {
      return {
         hello:'world',
      }
   },
   template:`<div>{{hello}}</div>`
}

var instance = defineComponent(component);

}
```

Use it within your template once you've instantiated it

```html
<component :is="instance" v-if="instance"/>
```

Comment: It worked for me with a component I load dynamically
```<component :is="instance" v-if="instance"/>```
and then in my setup
```let instance = ref(undefined); let modulePromise = import('../components/myComponent'); modulePromise.then((componentModule) => { instance.value = componentModule.default; }); ```

Answer (score 0):

When I migrated from Element UI to Element Plus I had to pass prefix/suffix icons as components and not as classname strings anymore. But I use single custom icon component and I have to first create a vnode and customize it with props and then pass it in as the
icon prop.

So I created a plugin:

```
import { createVNode, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export const createComponent = (component, props) => {
  try {
    if (component?.constructor === String) {
      const instance = getCurrentInstance()
      return createVNode(instance.appContext.components[component], props)
    } else {
      return createVNode(component, props)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to create VNode', component, props, err)
  }
}

export default {
  install(APP) {
    APP.$createComponent = createComponent
    APP.config.globalProperties.$createComponent = createComponent
  }
}
```

And then I can use it like this for globally registered components:

```
<component :is="$createComponent('my-global-component', { myProp1: 'myValue1', myProp2: 'myValue2' })" />
```

And for locally imported components:

```
<component :is="$createComponent(MyComponent, { foo: 'bar' }) />
```

Or

```
data() {
  return {
    customComponent: $createComponent(MyComponent, { foo: 'bar' })
  }
}

<template>
  <component :is="customComponent" />
  <MyOtherComponent :customizedComponent="customComponent" />
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out to extend the Button component and then append it root element `$el` to the referenced `container`:

```js
import Button from 'Button.vue'


const CompB = {
  extends: Button
}

this.$refs.container.appendChild(CompB.$el)
```

Comment: For me, this errored: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')`