# How to create new component with @vue/composition-api in TS file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, declare

I have some components that I need to create in the TS file. Usually, I create by calling new Component because on our project we have `vue-component-decorator` but now I'm starting using `@vue/composition-api` and I can't call any component as new.

Working:

```js
// SomeComponent.vue
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-component-decorator';

@Component
export default SomeComponent extends Vue {}

// Any .ts file
const component = new SomeComponent();
```

Not working:

```js
// SomeComponent.vue
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({});

// Any .ts file
const component = new SomeComponent();
```

Comment: Why do you need to programatically instanciate your components? Maybe there's a better solution

Comment: I need to insert the component into another HTML element without the Vue wrapper and the component should still be reactive

Comment: What do you mean without the Vue wrapper?

Comment: I have an empty ts file and I should be able to call any Vue component in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `createApp` to create the component and mount it programmatically:

```js
const myComponent = defineComponent({/* */})
createApp(myComponent, { /* Pass props here */ }).mount('#container');
```

Sources:

- github vuejs [issue#629](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/629#issuecomment-700549376)
- StackOverflow question [#64251487](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251487/vue3-creating-component-instances-programmatically-on-button-click)

Comment: How will that trick change performance of my application?